Phantom Wallet willl not let me withdraw my funds
I had funds in Smart Wallet and wanted to transfer this out to my bank account. They told me to send it to Phantom Wallet as they can't transfer to bank accounts. I did this and can see the amount correctly in the Phantom Wallet and had confirmation from both Smart Wallet and Phantom Wallet that the transaction had been succesful.
I then tried to transfer the funds from Phantom wallet to my bank account but the person assisting me from Phantom (Supposedly????) said I need to send $5,800 AUD to them for them to be able to release my money. When I said I couldn't do this and that I wished to transfer to another wallet that will allow me to withdraw the funds straight to my bank account they then sent me an email to say they had frozen my funds. I can't get any help from anyone at Phantom, they don't answer or the contact who had been emailing me just keeps saying there is nothing they can do as the legislation says I have to transfer this $5,800 and then withdraw it before they will let me withdraw my funds. Does anyone know if this is how it really works. I get the feeling that if I send that money I won't see it again and am super stressed about losing my crypto that is in the wallet. Thank you.

I'm really sorry to hear about your situation. Based on what you've described, it sounds like you might be dealing with a scam. Here are some steps you should take immediately:
Immediate Steps

Do Not Send Any More Money: It is highly suspicious that they are asking for an upfront payment to release your funds. This is not standard practice for legitimate wallets or exchanges.

Contact Phantom Wallet Support Directly: Use the official Phantom Wallet website and support channels to report the issue. Do not use any contact information provided by the person who is asking for money.

Report the Incident:

Local Authorities: File a report with your local police department as you might be a victim of fraud.
Australian Cyber Security Centre (ACSC): Report the scam to ACSC through their official website.
Australian Competition and Consumer Commission (ACCC): Report the scam to the ACCC’s Scamwatch.


Secure Your Accounts: Change passwords and enable two-factor authentication (2FA) on your cryptocurrency accounts and any related email accounts immediately.


Additional Steps

Check for Official Communication: Verify any emails you have received by contacting the support team of Smart Wallet and Phantom Wallet through their official websites.

Seek Legal Advice: Consult a lawyer who specializes in cryptocurrency or financial fraud for advice on how to proceed.


How to Identify a Scam

Unsolicited Contact: Be wary if someone contacts you unsolicited and asks for personal information or payments.

High-Pressure Tactics: Scammers often use high-pressure tactics to make you act quickly without thinking.

Upfront Fees: Legitimate companies typically do not require large upfront fees to release funds.

Lack of Contact Options: Legitimate companies have multiple ways to contact them, including verified phone numbers, email addresses, and physical addresses.


Resources

Phantom Wallet Support: Phantom Wallet Support
ACSC Reporting: Report to ACSC
Scamwatch Reporting: Report to Scamwatch
Local Police: Contact your local police department to file a report.

Final Note
Your instinct is correct; it is highly likely that if you send the $5,800 AUD, you may never see it again. Always ensure you are dealing with verified and official sources when managing your finances and reporting fraud.
